# Doctrine 2 one-to-one via composite key of both entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, foreign-keys

I have a question similar [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356848/doctrine-2-one-to-one-via-composite-key).

I need a relation one-to-one through composite key, is it possible? I've read about [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-1-dynamic-attributes) but it's referred to one-to-many relation

```
class Header{
    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="UH1", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $key1;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="UH2", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $key2;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Detail", mappedBy="header")
     */
    protected $detail;
} 

class Detail{
/**
     * 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="UD1", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $key1;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="UD2", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $key2;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Header", inversedBy="detail")
     */
    protected $header;
}
```

I mean there are two columns as Id per entity... do i need to add [the joincolumn](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`JoinColumns`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#joincolumns) annotation that allows to define an array of `JoinColumn` annotations to handle such cases for `ManyToOne` or `OneToOne` associations.

With the following entities:

<kbd>AppBundle\Entity\A.php</kbd>

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class A
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="key1", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $key1;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="key2", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $key2;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\B", mappedBy="a")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns(
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="key1", referencedColumnName="key1"),
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="key2", referencedColumnName="key2"),
     * )
     */
    private $b;
}
```

<kbd>AppBundle\Entity\B.php</kbd>

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class B
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="key1", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $key1;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="key2", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $key2;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\A", inversedBy="b")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns(
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="key1", referencedColumnName="key1"),
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="key2", referencedColumnName="key2"),
     * )
     */
    private $a;
}
```

I could achieve the desired behaviour. When asked for a schema update, Doctrine outputs:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a (key1 INT NOT NULL, key2 INT NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX b_uniq (key1, key2), PRIMARY KEY(key1, key2)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE b (key1 INT NOT NULL, key2 INT NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX a_uniq (key1, key2), PRIMARY KEY(key1, key2)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE a ADD CONSTRAINT FK_E8B7BE432C5C6450B55535EA FOREIGN KEY (key1, key2) REFERENCES b (key1, key2);
ALTER TABLE b ADD CONSTRAINT FK_71BEEFF92C5C6450B55535EA FOREIGN KEY (key1, key2) REFERENCES a (key1, key2);
```

Comment: Thank you, i've used the JoinColumns, this is my situation now (https://pastebin.com/PwYYW0Y5). The fact is that i have primary key columns used also as foreign key (no b_key* or a_key*), this is an existent database and i'm trying to write the correct Entity. Now i have an error `Missing value for primary key UD1 on Details`

Comment: @JackSkeletron You are not using the right syntax for `JoinColumns`. It needs to be `@ORM\JoinColumns(...)` and not `@ORM\JoinColumns={...}`. Curiously, Doctrine will not consider it as an error but the output given for the schema update will only consider one field instead of two. I updated my answer so that it can fit your specific use case. The schema given by Doctrine contains, as expected, only two fields for A and B which are then marked as foreign keys.

Comment: thank you very much! It worked, i've read about that notation [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-joincolumns)

Comment: Ah I see. I think you mixed up the example given there that was about the `joinColumns` attribute of the `JoinTable` annotation with the `JoinColumns` annotation section which does not have any example at all.  Either way, glad that I could help :)